# Parsing AWS S3 Streaming logs for total bandwidth

Tags: logging, amazon-web-services, streaming

I am parsing an Amazon S3 streaming log file in the hope of obtaining daily cumulative streaming usage for video and audio assets.

However the totals that I am able to pull out of these logs for say August are at least half of what the AWS dashboard bill says was used. Having looked at the documentation the sc-byte count field provided in the [logs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) is a running total up to the time of the event (play, pause, stop, disconnect etc.)

Our bill says we used 22GB of data in August but capturing the disconnect event, which would presumably be the final byte count for that users session, shows a 10GB data usage.  Any other combination of capturing the sc-byte count either results in a figure way too high or at least half of what we have actually been billed in the AWS console.

Has anyone created anything similar who might be able to shed some light on what accurately represents the usage streaming bandwidth in a session, from the log files, which can be aggregated to produce a daily and later monthly usage count?